# jQuery: Mirror the combination of two input fields into a third input

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to try and modify the existing jQuery I have which mirrors two input fields:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#forename').bind('keypress', function() 
        {
            $('#displayname').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I actually need is for the "displayname" field to be a combination of *two* fields with the ids: #forename + #surname
... with a space in between.

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the event to the surname as well, changed to `keyup` to grab the new value:

```
    $('#forename,#surname').on('keyup', function() 
    {
        $('#displayname').val($('#forename').val() + ' ' + $('#surname').val());
    });
```

Note: If displayname is not an input, use `text` instead of `val` to set its content

Comment: This works perfectly. I can also see how the code is working from that. Thank you so much.